# How to use util constants in router expression?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've defined these util constants in my context.

```
<util:constant id="foo1" static-field="com.marvel.avengers.hulc.util.MyExampleConstants.FOO1"/>
<util:constant id="foo2" static-field="com.marvel.avengers.hulc.util.MyExampleConstants.FOO2"/>
<util:constant id="foo3" static-field="com.marvel.avengers.hulc.util.MyExampleConstants.FOO3"/>
```

I've tried using foo1 constant in my router expression, but it looks like #{foo1} is a bean id and not its value.

```
<int:router input-channel="channelABC" expression=" !payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(#{foo1}) 
        and !payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(#{foo2}) 
        and !payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(#{foo3}) ? 'flowEndpoint' : 'civilWarsChan'"/>
```

On the other hand I could use this in an expression but want to see if I could make use of the constants that I've defined in the router expression:

```
<int:router input-channel="channelABC" expression=" !payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(T(com.marvel.avengers.hulc.util.MyExampleConstants).FOO1) 
    and !payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(T(com.marvel.avengers.hulc.util.MyExampleConstants).FOO2) 
    and !payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(T(com.marvel.avengers.hulc.util.MyExampleConstants).FOO3) ? 'flowEndpoint' : 'civilWarsChan'"/>
```

Can someone help me to know, how to get value from this bean in router expression.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
!payload.avengersVO.powType.equals(@foo2)
```

Although, your case looks for me fine, too:

```
<util:constant id="foo" static-field="org.springframework.integration.router.config.RouterParserTests.FOO"/>

<router input-channel="constantExpressionRouter" expression="'#{foo}'"/>
```

However, pay attention that I wrap the Bean Definition expression into the literal quotes to avoid an attempt to evaluate it as a property at runtime on each message.